# Is the space of continuous functions from Polish space to Polish space Polish?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Theorem 4.19 in Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory says that the space of continuous functions from a compact metric space to a Polish space is Polish. It is therefore obvious that the space of continuous functions from a compact Polish space to a Polish space is Polish.

The space of continuous function is equipped with a product metric, for example, the Chebyshev metric.

> My question is, can we drop the "compactness"?

What anomaly would arise?

If we drop the "continuity", then some problems would arise for cardinality. However, with continuity, we don't have this problem.

Comment: Consider $C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: $K$ compact, $X$ metric: For space $C(K,X)$ use uniform convergence.  (I assume Kechris says this somewhere before 4.19.)  With other domains, for $C(Y,X)$ try the compact-open topology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology When $Y$ is locally compact Hausdorff, this still has some good properties.

Comment: I suppose that if this is the question you wanted to ask over there (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351160/x-is-polish-and-n-is-countable-is-nx-polish/351182#351182), you should edit the other question and delete this one.

Comment: @Arno. Re: "you should edit the other question and delete this one"... Please keep in mind that High GPA is a new MathOverflow poster. Let's try to be gentle and welcoming.

Comment: Chebyshev? -- r'u sure?

Comment: @Arno They are different questions, in my humble opinion, because the other question does not really "work" but this one would possibly "work" in my guesses because continuity is imposed.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what topology you have in mind to put on the space of continuous functions.  You say "a product metric" but as far as I can tell, the "Chebyshev metric" would induce the uniform topology, not the product topology.  Can you please specify the topology precisely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already answered here ([$X$ is Polish and $N$ is countable. Is $N^X$ Polish?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351160/x-is-polish-and-n-is-countable-is-nx-polish/351182#351182)):

Let us work in a convenient category of topological spaces, ie assume that we have function spaces and sufficiently many nice spaces around. My favourite such category is the category of $\mathrm{QCB}_0$-spaces, which are $T_0$ quotients of countably-based spaces [1].

Inside the category of $\mathrm{QCB}_0$-spaces, Schröder has obtained a characterization of the Hausdorff spaces $\mathbf{X}$ such that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbf{X}$ is Polish [2]. These spaces are now called coPolish spaces. A Polish space is coPolish iff it is locally compact. So we can weaken compactness to local compactness, but not further.

A space such as $2^{(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})}$ even fails to be countably based.

[1] https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397501001098

[2] https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/malq.200310111

Comment: The other question does not involve continuity, though, so in my humble opinion, they are quite different